# Net position calculation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of orders that looks like this:

```
Ticket  Open Time               Close Time              Type    Size
253199  2010-09-09 20:40:00     2010-09-09 20:41:00     sell    0.1
255406  2010-09-13 19:30:00     2010-09-14 04:30:00     buy     0.1
258089  2010-09-15 07:00:00     2010-09-15 09:15:00     sell    0.1
258197  2010-09-15 09:15:00     2010-09-15 14:50:00     buy     0.1
258203  2010-09-15 09:20:00     2010-09-15 14:50:00     buy     0.1
259659  2010-09-16 04:35:00     2010-09-16 18:35:00     sell    0.1
261065  2010-09-17 07:05:00     2010-09-20 00:02:00     buy     0.1
```

For each order I would like to get a cumulative total of all orders (of the same `Type`) that are simultaneously opened. In other words, a sum of all `Size` of any order that opened before the given order and closed after the given order.

Here is my code:

```
DROP TABLE
IF EXISTS LongOrders;

CREATE TABLE LongOrders SELECT 
    B.Ticket AS Ticket,
    SUM(B.`Size`)AS `Cumulative Long`
FROM
    `orders`.eurusd_fx AS A
JOIN `orders`.eurusd_fx AS B ON(
    B.`Close Time` >= A.`Open Time`
    AND B.`Open Time` <= A.`Open Time`
    AND A.Type = B.Type
    AND A.Type = 'buy'
)
GROUP BY
    A.`Open Time`
ORDER BY
    A.`Open Time`;

DROP TABLE
IF EXISTS ShortOrders;

CREATE TABLE ShortOrders SELECT
    B.Ticket AS Ticket,
    SUM(B.`Size`)AS `Cumulative Short`
FROM
    `orders`.eurusd_fx AS A
JOIN `orders`.eurusd_fx AS B ON(
    B.`Close Time` >= A.`Open Time`
  AND B.`Open Time` <= A.`Open Time`
    AND A.Type = B.Type
    AND A.Type = 'sell'
)
GROUP BY
    A.`Open Time`
ORDER BY
    A.`Open Time`;

DROP TABLE
IF EXISTS CumLong;

CREATE TABLE CumLong SELECT
    A.*
FROM
    LongOrders AS A
JOIN `orders`.eurusd_fx AS B USING(Ticket);

DROP TABLE
IF EXISTS CumShort;

CREATE TABLE CumShort SELECT
    A.*
FROM
    ShortOrders AS A
JOIN `orders`.eurusd_fx AS B USING(Ticket);

SELECT DISTINCT
    A.*, CumLong.`Cumulative Long`,
    CumShort.`Cumulative Short`
FROM
    `orders`.eurusd_fx AS A
JOIN(CumShort, CumLong)ON(
    A.Ticket = CumLong.Ticket
    OR A.Ticket = CumShort.Ticket
) GROUP  BY A.`Open Time`;
```

And the output:

```
+--------+---------------------+------+------+--------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+
| Ticket | Open Time           | Type | Size | Item   | Close Time          | Commission | Cumulative Long | Cumulative Short |
+--------+---------------------+------+------+--------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+
| 253199 | 2010-09-09 20:40:00 | sell |  0.1 | eurusd | 2010-09-09 20:41:00 | -0.89      |         0.10000 |          0.10000 |
| 255406 | 2010-09-13 19:30:00 | buy  |  0.1 | eurusd | 2010-09-14 04:30:00 | -0.9       |         0.10000 |          0.10000 |
| 258089 | 2010-09-15 07:00:00 | sell |  0.1 | eurusd | 2010-09-15 09:15:00 | -0.91      |         0.10000 |          0.10000 |
| 258197 | 2010-09-15 09:15:00 | buy  |  0.1 | eurusd | 2010-09-15 14:50:00 | -0.91      |         0.10000 |          0.10000 |
| 259659 | 2010-09-16 04:35:00 | sell |  0.1 | eurusd | 2010-09-16 18:35:00 | -0.91      |         0.10000 |          0.10000 |
| 261065 | 2010-09-17 07:05:00 | buy  |  0.1 | eurusd | 2010-09-20 00:02:00 | -0.92      |         0.10000 |          0.10000 |
| 262121 | 2010-09-20 03:00:00 | sell |  0.1 | eurusd | 2010-09-20 05:55:00 | -0.91      |         0.10000 |          0.10000 |
| 262192 | 2010-09-20 05:50:00 | buy  |  0.1 | eurusd | 2010-09-20 09:50:00 | -0.92      |         0.10000 |          0.10000 |
| 262739 | 2010-09-20 16:55:00 | sell |  0.1 | eurusd | 2010-09-20 18:45:00 | -0.91      |         0.10000 |          0.90000 |
| 262822 | 2010-09-20 18:40:00 | buy  |  0.1 | eurusd | 2010-09-21 02:05:00 | -0.92      |         0.10000 |          0.10000 |
| 263801 | 2010-09-21 13:05:00 | buy  |  0.1 | eurusd | 2010-09-21 21:25:00 | -0.92      |         0.40000 |          0.10000 |
```

It does not seem to work properly. For instance the Cumulative Long for the first `sell` should be 0.

I'd really appreciate some help! Thanks.

Edit: 1 more question: How can I get the value for `ABS(`Cumulative Long`-`Cumulative Short`)`? I need the NET cumulative position size.

Comment: you need some kind of analytic function for this: they are not available in MySQL but can be emulated: see e.g. http://onlamp.com/pub/a/mysql/2007/03/29/emulating-analytic-aka-ranking-functions-with-mysql.html or http://explainextended.com/2009/03/12/analytic-functions-optimizing-lag-lead-first_value-last_value/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    A.*
  , SUM(CASE WHEN B.Type = 'buy'  THEN B.Size ELSE 0 END)
    AS `Cumulative Long`
  , SUM(CASE WHEN B.Type = 'sell' THEN B.Size ELSE 0 END) 
    AS `Cumulative Short`
FROM
  orders.eurusd_fx AS A
    JOIN
  orders.eurusd_fx AS B
      ON  B.`Open Time` <= A.`Open Time` 
      AND A.`Open Time` <= B.`Close Time` 
GROUP BY
    A.Ticket
ORDER BY
    A.`Open Time`
  , A.Ticket ;
```

or

```
SELECT 
    A.*
  , ( SELECT COALESCE(SUM(B.Size),0)
      FROM orders.eurusd_fx AS B
      WHERE B.`Open Time` <= A.`Open Time` 
        AND A.`Open Time` <= B.`Close Time` 
        AND B.Type = 'buy' 
    ) AS `Cumulative Long`
  , ( SELECT COALESCE(SUM(C.Size),0)
      FROM orders.eurusd_fx AS C
      WHERE C.`Open Time` <= A.`Open Time` 
        AND A.`Open Time` <= C.`Close Time` 
        AND C.Type = 'sell' 
    ) AS `Cumulative Short`
FROM
  orders.eurusd_fx AS A
ORDER BY
    A.`Open Time`
  , A.Ticket ;
```

---

To get that extra calculation, you either add another calulated column or add an extra layer (pushing the `ORDER BY` to that exterior layer):

```
SELECT tmp.*
     , ABS(`Cumulative Long` - `Cumulative Short`) AS NetCumulativeSize 
FROM
  ( SELECT 
        A.*
      , SUM(CASE WHEN B.Type = 'buy'  THEN B.Size ELSE 0 END)
        AS `Cumulative Long`
      , SUM(CASE WHEN B.Type = 'sell' THEN B.Size ELSE 0 END) 
        AS `Cumulative Short`
    FROM
      orders.eurusd_fx AS A
        JOIN
      orders.eurusd_fx AS B
          ON  B.`Open Time` <= A.`Open Time` 
          AND A.`Open Time` <= B.`Close Time` 
    GROUP BY
        A.Ticket
  ) AS tmp
ORDER BY
    tmp.`Open Time`
  , tmp.Ticket ;
```

Comment: Excellent, Thanks! 1 more question: How can I get the value for `ABS(`Cumulative Long` - `Cumulative Short`)`? I need the NET cumulative position size.

Comment: My intuition tells me the ON clause should read: b.opentime <= a.closetime, to have an overlapping time. Suppose order A runs from 2 to 7. Order B has 4 different overlap possibilities: 1 to 8, 1 to 3, 4 to 5, 6 to 8. With 3 open and 1 close in the ON you select 2 (1 to 8 and 1 to 3) of them, with 2 open and 2 close you select all 4. From the requirements it's unclear to me which is correct.

Comment: @Martin: I think he doesn't want overlaping over all `(A.OpenTime, A.CloseTime)` period, but to find other orders (B) that are open at the moment when an order (A) opens.

Comment: if he wants to find only open orders, then there's the <= in both comparisons, which may lead to counting twice. I'd put a < on the closing time, not <=. He'll have to do a bit of testing various situations before handing it in for production.

Comment: @Martin: What I understood was that he wanted to check `A.OpenTime BETWEEN B.OpenTime AND B.CloseTime`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understand your requirement. If wrong please clarify.

```
SELECT 
    A.Ticket AS Ticket,
    SUM(B.`Size`) AS `Cumulative Long`
FROM
    `orders`.eurusd_fx AS A
JOIN `orders`.eurusd_fx AS B ON (
    B.`Close Time` >= A.`Open Time`
    AND B.`Open Time` <= A.`Open Time`
    AND A.Type = B.Type
    AND A.Type = 'buy'
)
GROUP BY
    A.`Ticket`
ORDER BY
    A.`Ticket`;
```

Comment: Yes that is correct... but when I use that my final result shows 0.01 for Cumulative Long for the first order, even though the first order is a sell.

Comment: It should be B.Type instead of A.Type : `AND B.Type = 'buy'`

Answer (score 0):

I inserted my test data with different ticket numbers, by that won't change the procedure.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*, CumLong.`Cumulative Long`, CumShort.`Cumulative Short` 

FROM `orders`.eurusd_fx AS A

LEFT JOIN Cumlong ON A.Ticket = CumLong.Ticket

LEFT JOIN cumshort ON A.Ticket = Cumshort.Ticket

GROUP BY A.`Open Time`
```

results in:

```
ticket open time   close time               type size Cumulative Long    Cumulative Short

1   2010-09-09 20:40:00  2010-09-09 20:41:00 sell 0.1 NULL               0.100000001490116

2   2010-09-13 19:30:00  2010-09-14 04:30:00 buy  0.1 0.100000001490116  NULL

3   2010-09-15 07:00:00  2010-09-15 09:15:00 sell 0.1 NULL               0.100000001490116

4   2010-09-15 09:15:00  2010-09-15 14:50:00 buy  0.1 0.100000001490116  NULL

5   2010-09-15 09:20:00  2010-09-15 14:50:00 buy  0.1 NULL               NULL

6   2010-09-16 04:35:00  2010-09-16 18:35:00 sell 0.1 NULL               0.100000001490116

7   2010-09-17 07:05:00  2010-09-20 00:02:00 buy  0.1 0.100000001490116  NULL
```

That's what you want? I don't think so, as the only order open while another was open too is nr 258203. Nr 258197 closes at the same time as 258203 but opens before (I understand that in case of overlap in time you want the one thar starts earlier)

So I guess that the outcome should be one line with order 258203  with a short of 0,.2?